# Performing Searches over Many-to-Many Relationships

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many, relationship

I have a database which (for the purposes of this example), has two tables that have a many to many association (with an intermediary table for holding the associations). Here is there structure:

Table A:

```
+-----+-------+-------+-------+
| aID | aCol1 | aCol2 | aCol3 |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+
|  1  |  foo  |  aoo  |  doo  |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+
|  2  |  bar  |  aar  |  dar  |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+
|  3  |  baz  |  aaz  |  daz  |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+
```

Table B:

```
+-----+-------+
| bID | bCol1 |
+-----+-------+
|  1  | alice |
+-----+-------+
|  2  |  bob  |
+-----+-------+
```

Association Table:

```
+-----+-----+
| aID | bID |
+-----+-----+
|  1  |  1  |
+-----+-----+
|  2  |  2  |
+-----+-----+
|  3  |  1  |
+-----+-----+
```

If I want to search for information by aCol2 LIKE 'aa%' AND the row has an association to bCol1 = 'bob' (i.e. resulting in only row aID = 2), how could I assemble a MySQL Query that could do something similar?

p.s. Sorry for the poor clarity, I am not exactly sure of the wording, but in a nut shell, it is about searching for data from one record that (for the purposes of this) has a 1-* relationship via a connecting table to a number of records, by information that exists in the entire set

Comment: Although I know this can easily by done by performing a search for each found record on the associated data, then if the resulting rows aren't right, it will remove it from the array of found rows, but I am trying to avoid the N + 1 query select problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been awhile, but I believe this should work:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    A,
    B,
    associations
WHERE
    A.aCol2 LIKE 'aa%' AND
    A.aID = associations.aID AND
    associations.bID = B.bID
```

You have to do 2 inner joins to combine the 3 tables.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM
    table_b b
    INNER JOIN associations ab ON (b.b_id = ab.b_id)
    INNER JOIN table_a a ON (ab.a_id = a.a_id)
WHERE
    b.col_1 = 'bob'
    AND a.col_2 LIKE 'aa%'
```